# Clean URLs for images

Tags: php, apache, url, .htaccess

I'm unable to get a working .htaccess that should accept clean URLs to load images. I mean, for example, if a user type this:

http://mysite.com/image/example

It works perfectly, as my PHP process and parse it. However, if the user type:

.../image/example.jpg

It doesn't work. I mean, if a user writes that, I want to load the module with the example.jpg as a parameter, I don't want to load the image at all!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough. Where is the user typing "../image/example.jpg"? In the address bar? In some source code on your server? In a CSS file? I don't understand what's being asked here.

Comment: And how about showing the .htaccess file in question? The old crystal ball being at the cleaners' etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a directory called "image" and files (such as example.jpg) in this directory then htaccess will allow the user to view the file if you have the line: "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f" in your htaccess file.

"RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f" means the htaccess file will accepts urls if they point to a file.  Try removing this line from you htaccess if you have it in there.

Hope this helps

Regards
Luke